# Incrementing Multi Dimensional Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm currently working on something very basic but I am having a hard time. I would like to get a random index in a two dimensional array and increment it by one every time the for-loop turns over.

```
var dice = [[],[]];

// Get totals.
for(var i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
    var dieOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    var dieTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        dice[[dieOne][dieTwo]]++;
    }

    // All index values equal 30,000 for some reason
    alert(dice[[1][3]]);
```

Why would this for loop set all indexes to 30,000? Am I using JavaScript arrays incorrectly?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: How do you expect to be your output array?

Comment: I am expecting the array to increment by one at random points between 1 and 6.

For example if dieOne = 5 and dieTwo = 3, I would expect dice[5][3] to increment by one.

Comment: Actually [your code alerts](http://jsfiddle.net/UYYuv/) `NaN`. `dice[[dieOne][dieTwo]]++;` doesn't make any sense, since `[dieOne][dieTwo]` can't be converted to an integer...

Comment: Interesting.. I never got NaN on my side. Just a popup with 30,000 in it. Using Safari.

Comment: @JamesManes Hmm... I tested your code with Chrome30, FF24 and IE10, all alerted `NaN`. Smells like a bug in Safari? Or you've typos in your post? `[dieOne][dieTwo]` are just two anonymous arrays with a random indicies, both are evaluated as `undefined`. The same stands for the `alert([[1][3]]), argument is just some newly created arrays...

Comment: @JamesManes according to the ES5 standard, coercing `undefined` to a number should result in `NaN`, not `0`, so Safari is being naughty.  But you didn't want `NaN` or `30000`, so the point is moot (unless you're in charge of maintaining Safari).  My answer explains why you're getting `30000` and they're getting `NaN` with browsers that follow the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you're doing**

It seems like you're misunderstanding the syntax of what you're doing. It is currently equivalent to

```
var dieOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
var dieTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
var foo;
foo = dieOne; // a number
foo = [foo];  // an array with one number in it
foo = foo[dieTwo]; // probably undefined, unlikely case of `dieTwo = 0`
                   // which would give back `dieOne`
dice[foo] = dice[foo] + 1; // most likely trying to add 1 to property `undefined`
```

Then later you're doing

```
foo = [1]; // an array length 1
foo = foo[3]; // undefined, it doesn't have an item here
foo = dice[foo]; // = dice[undefined] = undefined
alert(foo); // alerting "undefined"
```

---

**What you probably want to be doing**

It looks like you actually want an *Array* of `6` *Arrays* each of `6` *Numbers*; construct your favourite way

```
var dice = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];
```

Then for your loop to be

```
var dieOne, dieTwo, i;
for(i = 0; i < 30000; ++i) {
    dieOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); // indices start at 0 and
    dieTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); // 6 of them means max is 5
    dice[dieOne][dieTwo]++; // count the brackets here..
}
```

then say you want to know how many times you had *dieOne = 1, dieTwo = 3*, you would look at

```
dice[1][3]; // count the brackets again.
```

Comment: I've tried setting all indexes to zero within a loop like so dice[[i][j]] = 0; and it still does not work. Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean as "undefined?"

Comment: Please read again where I describe what happens to `foo`. I use `foo` to break your line of code down into a step-by-step of what the interpreter tries to do with your code.

Comment: Hmm.. so in JavaScript I cannot create a 6x6 grid with a two dimensional array, I must make a 6 arrays, each filled with 6 values. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "two dimensional array" in _JavaScript_.

Comment: Alright. Sorry if my questions seem borderline annoying. Not having two dimensional arrays at my disposal is a bit new to me. I will try what you have provided.

Comment: I tried what you provided and I am being told that "'undefined' is not an object." It is saying this in reference to the increment line.

Comment: @JamesManes in the first two code blocks I am explaining your code. In the last 3 I am giving you an alternative **edit** made it more obvious

Comment: I tried the last two blocks. If I increment the array like so dice[0][0]++; it works and adds up to 30,000. However, if I increment using the variables like so dice[dieOne][dieTwo]++; it throws the undefined error.

Comment: @JamesManes did you change the random number generation too? remember that you actually only want to go up to `5` because `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].length === 6`

Comment: AHHHHH now THAT fixed it! Thank you for your help. Little things can be quite important. :) Thanks for your patients with me. I can get it from here!

Comment: @PaulS. An interesting point in this question is the alerted result in Safari, can you explain that?

Comment: @Teemu I don't have _Safari_, but from what was said, I'm guessing if you have `var x; // undefined` and do `x++`, then _Safari_ gives `1` and everywhere else gives `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

This, while (unfortunately) technically valid JavaScript, is not going to do what you want:

```
dice[[dieOne][dieTwo]]
```

The expression `foo[bar]` is a reference to `foo`'s property named `bar`.  Property keys are always strings or numeric (technically just strings, but if we're talking about arrays, it makes more sense to think of keys as numbers).  Thus when JavaScript sees the expression `dice[[dieOne][dieTwo]]` it tries to coerce `[dieOne][dieTwo]` into a valid property key.  Wackiness ensues as follows:

- `[dieOne]` evaluates to an array containing one element at index 0 whose value is `dieOne`; let that intermediate result be hereafter referred to as `foo`.
- `foo[dieTwo]` evaluates to a reference to the property of `foo` whose index is `dieTwo`
- Since, in every iteration of your loop, `dieTwo` is always > 0, and `foo` is an array whose only valid index is `0`, `dieTwo` is out of bounds.  Sadly, the array returns `undefined` instead of throwing an error.
- The value `undefined` is coerced to a string so it can be used as a property key.  Technically, only strings are property keys; arrays are sort of faked, according to the standard.  The value is `"undefined"`.
- Since your code hasn't assigned a value to `dice["undefined"]`, the first attempt to `++` it sees its initial value as, again, `undefined`.  And again, instead of throwing an exception, it unfortunately coerces `undefined` into what it looks like you want, the number `0`, increments to `1`, and assigns it to the newly defined `dice["undefined"]`.

  - If your browser was following the ES5 standard, `undefined++` would be `NaN`.
- Since following the steps above, `[dieOne][dieTwo]` is ALWAYS coerced to `"undefined"`, said property of `dice` is incremented once on each iteration of the loop, giving it a final value of `30000`.

  - If your browser was following the ES5 standard, `NaN++` would be `NaN`, no matter how many times you increment it.
- Since ANY `[foo][bar]` where `bar` is not `0`, when coerced to a property key, will be `"undefined"` according to the steps above, `dice[[n][m]]` is ALWAYS equivalent to `dice["undefined"]`.  Just for fun, try `dice[[n][0]]` where `n` is absolutely anything other than `"undefined"` to verify that it is not `30000` and that I am therefore right and deserve a check mark =D.

So that's why you're getting that particular result.

There aren't real multidimensional arrays in JS, and you'll be much less confused about the syntax if you think of it instead as an array of arrays.  Then you can break it down into steps:

- `dice` is an array of arrays of numbers,
- so `dice[n]` is an array of numbers,
- so `dice[n][m]` is the number I want.

So here's roughly what your correct program will look like:

```
/* We don't like undefined anymore, so make an array of 7 arrays of 7 zeroes */
/* (we need 7 because JS array indexes start at 0 and you're using values 1-6) */
var dice = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
];
/* Now I'm tired of repeating myself, so let's DRY things up */
function roll() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
}
var dieOne, dieTwo;
for ( var i = 0 ; i < 30000 ; i++ ) {
    dieOne = roll();
    dieTwo = roll();
    dice[dieOne][dieTwo]++;
}
```

The most important part to look at is the last line.

- `dice` is an array of array of numbers,
- so `dice[dieOne]` is an array of numbers,
- so `dice[dieOne][dieTwo]` is a number we can increment meaningfully.

Comment: I think this answer explains exactly what is happening in the original code more clearly than mine so `+1`, but what you say about following _ES5_ - it isn't the first standard for it to be true; this behaviour is also in _ES3_, [**spec**](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf); sections 11.3.1 for _Postfix Increment Operator_ and 9.4 for _ToNumber_.

Comment: @PaulS Absolutely right; I say ES5 because that's what I had in front of me =D  Thanks for the clarification